# Control init lag at startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I get a small lag at the controls I'm using when I start up my app. Can I show the main form *after* the controls are drawn?

Comment: Are you saying that when the main form appears the controls don't show up immediately?

Comment: I think yes. The controls appear after the form is showed.

Answer (score 1):

Try subscribing to the `Application.Idle` event inside your form's load method, and unsubscribing from it once invoked. Like this:

```
public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
    // any loading prep code here
}

private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
    // additional code here, which is executed *after* controls are visible and loaded
}
```